# WPF Update UI while loading

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker, threadpool, dispatcher

I want to update the UI while loading some long work. What I want is when the data is loading I want to show an `UserControl` which is nothing but a wait message. I have tried `BackgroundWorker`, `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` and `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` but I dont know why it is not doing as per the expectation. Please help

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible));
//Load some long wok here           
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

What I am looking for is to show an Image while loading and when load finish it must be collapsed.

**Edit:**

```
<Grid Grid.Column="2"
      Name="DetailsPane">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="img/back.jpg"
                    Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <Image Name="img"
           Margin="5"
           Stretch="None"
           Visibility="Collapsed" 
           Source="img/Loading.png" />
</Grid>
```

I have a Image to show while a loading is going on the Listbox SelectionChanged. So inside the SelectionChanged Event I'll be loading a detailed info in the Grid Called DetailsPane of a particular thing Cliked on the ListBox. While the loading of the info takes place **how should I be showing this image on the DetailsPane**?

---

**Reached till here**

Created a Dependency Property called State of type bool, then

### .CS

```
private void LstAllFeatures_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    State = false;
    // Loading Heavy Work 
     State = true;
}
```

### XAML

```
<Image Name="img"
       Margin="5"
       Stretch="None">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Collapsed" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}"
                             Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility"
                            Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

In `DeatilsPane.Children` -> `_visualChildren` -> `InternalArray[0]` is a Image. When open that in the WPF Visualizer Shows the Image Visibility = Visible but it doesn't show. Any Light on it please.

Comment: are you running this piece of code on a background thread?

Comment: No Currently in this code I have removed BackgroundWorker and ThreadPool. It is just Dispatcher.BeginInvoke and just tried this code 'DispatcherPriority.Background' which actually gives an flickeration that I can see it else anyother code doesnt show it at all.

Comment: `Long running work` should be run on a background thread, or the UI becomes unresponsive. You had tried both `BackgroundWorker` and `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, they should work. Could you show the code that you call `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`?

Comment: You want to be doing the long work on another thread and marshal updates.  If you are attempting to do long work on the UI thread any attempt to update the UI won't appear until the message pump is processed, which you sadly have blocked

Comment: //Load some long wok here           
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed), DispatcherPriority.Background);
Is this what you are doing when running the long work ?  because it's Collapsed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first userControl must implement INotifyPropertyChanged like:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string      propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

then State must definition like:

```
public bool _state;
public bool State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _state)
            {
                _state= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

then in code where you want call LongWork()

```
State = true;
await Task.Run(()=>LongWork());
State = fasle;
```

then in xaml you write like:

```
<Image Margin="5"
   Stretch="None">
<Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="Visibility"
                Value="Collapsed" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State,RelativeSource=   {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type test:UserControlName}},Mode=TwoWay}"
                         Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
   </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `bool` property:

```
public bool IsLoading
{
    get { return isLoading; }
    set { isLoading = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("IsLoading"); }
}
```

Data bind it to the `Image.Visibility` property:

```
<Image Margin="5" Stretch="None" Source="img/Loading.png"> 
    <Image .Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLoading}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Set it to `true` when you start your long running task *on a background thread*:

```
IsLoading = true;
```

Set it to `false` when your long running process is complete:

```
IsLoading = false;
```

Note that this will only work if you run your long running process on a background thread, otherwise, the UI thread will be busy and not update.